# Sum of the arctangents of roots of a cubic equation (multiple choice)

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> If $A$, $B$, and $C$ are the roots of the equation $x^3+mx^2+3x+m=0$, then the value of  $$\arctan(A)+\arctan(B)+\arctan(C)$$is given by
>
> **A.** $n\pi$
> **B.** $n\pi/2$
> **C.** $\pi(2n+1)/2$
> **D.** none

I met this question in JEE Exams of GOIIT but my human ability couldn't solve and I messed up on this question despite being a multiple choice question.

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1bfb09c6-bf3a-4a35-a2b7-08a317bf332f/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: @zev chonoles thanks but nothing was change in your edit

Comment: A bit away from the question,how do I edit my account here?

Comment: I have noticed that you have now asked 10 questions without accepting a single one.  You may wish to accept solutions you find useful by clicking the check mark to the left of those solutions.

Comment: You have asked $18$ questions without  accepting an answer. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 6):

First, prove that

$$\arctan{A}+\arctan{B}+\arctan{C} = \arctan{\frac{A+B+C-ABC}{1-(AB+AC+BC)}}$$

Do this by observing that

$$\arctan{X}+\arctan{Y} = \arctan{\frac{X+Y}{1-XY}}$$

Then note that

$$A+B+C = ABC = -m$$

Thus the sum of the arctangents of the roots is

$$\arctan{0} = n \pi $$

for some $n \in \mathbb{Z}$